# Google Sheets - Pivot table is breaking every time the data sheet powering the pivot is updated

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table

I have a google-sheet with a protected (padlocked) raw-data sheet which is being updated by a third party. I have a pivot table based on this data sheet which is breaking every day when the data sheet is updated.

Each day the pivot range resets to 1:1 (when it was A:D) and the rows and values in the pivot are lost.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening, maybe even creating an automation to auto create the pivot?

When I first created the pivot and select the range, it was the exact range of A1:D64800

Because the dataset is very large, I thought the issue was because the sheet had no free rows and it was expanding its range. I switched the range of my pivot to A:D to cover all eventualities, this did not fix it.

I have tried importing the data sheet range to a different sheet but it's too big.

Comment: I just searched some stuff to try to relate this to my Excel knowledge, and found some docs saying Google Sheets is limited to 40K rows. Is your sheet somehow larger than that? In any case, there's probably a function that gets the number of rows and columns. Try using that instead of hard coding it.

Comment: I'm guessing that you initially created the pivot table manually. But it sounds like you needs a script to reset the range(s), if not some/all of the other parameters.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede `and found some docs saying Google Sheets is limited to 40K rows.` Would you provide a citation please?

Comment: `Each day the pivot range resets to 1:1 (when it was A:D)` I have tried but I can't reproduce this problem. I've tried `IMPORTRANGE` from a second sheet but the pivot range of `A:H` doesn't change even when I delete all the data (and delete most of the columns) from the other sheet. I suggest that you create a script that will "build" the pivot table - [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#create_a_pivot_table).